# Has anyone created or found stats for Lloyd Slate in the Dresden Files RPG?

Tags: dresden-files

I'm filling in as the GM for my group for a while, and I'm pretty shaky on doing new stats.  I need Slate for an upcoming session, and I think they're going to want to fight him.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

If you have [the *Our World* manual](http://www.evilhat.com/home/dresden-files-rpg-our-world/), Lloyd Slate is on pages 227-228. He's got a total Refresh cost of -11!

(There's a note on his character block which points out Slate wasn't seen in combat in the case files, so his combat abilities are based on educated guesses.)

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for the link! I'm on it. -11 is a LOT...I'm wondering if it's a really bad idea for my players to take him on. I'm pretty new to Fate games-my GM background is primarily D&D, and I'm having a hard time planning appropriate encounters. I tend to plan too easy or too hard. What kind of group would it take to go toe to toe with a -11?

Comment: Depends a lot on who they are and how prepared they are, but Fate games don't need to be balanced as aggressively as D&D. Because losing rarely means dying, just making things more complicated--and because you can concede the fight if it's looking bad--sometimes being seriously overmatched is a *good* thing for the story! If you've got more specific questions, make it a new question on the site.

Comment: Given the changes in ability the next Winter Knight gets, and those that Summer Knight Fix gets, it's entirely possible that the stats undervalue him.